# Mongo DB modify elements in nested arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongo-shell

I am wondering how can I change the element in such array in Mongo DB. Say the collections is as follow:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),

"user_info" : {
    "user_name" : "joe",        
},

"portfolio" : [ 
    {
        "market_symbol" : "NASDAQ:GOOGL",
        "details" : [ 
            {
                "amount" : 100,
                "purchased_price" : 810.25,
                "date_of_purchase" : "20170210 212426"
            }, 
            {
                "amount" : 100,
                "purchased_price" : 810.25,
                "date_of_purchase" : "20170210 212426"
            }, 
            {
                "amount" : 200,
                "purchased_price" : 900.0,
                "date_of_purchase" : "20170210 212426"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "market_symbol" : "NYSE:BABA",
        "details" : [ 
            {
                "amount" : 200,
                "purchased_price" : 80.0,
                "date_of_purchase" : "20170210 212426"
            }, 
            {
                "amount" : 333,
                "purchased_price" : 86.11,
                "date_of_purchase" : "20170210 212426"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am trying to modify the value of 
`amount` in `"portfolio:market_symbol":"NASDAQ:GOOGL"`, where the `purchased_price` is `900` and I want to set the 200 to 300.

so the segment should look like this after the modification:

```
"portfolio" : [ 
{
    "market_symbol" : "NASDAQ:GOOGL",
    "details" : [ 
        {
            "amount" : 100,
            "purchased_price" : 810.25,
            "date_of_purchase" : "20170210 212426"
        }, 
        {
            "amount" : 100,
            "purchased_price" : 810.25,
            "date_of_purchase" : "20170210 212426"
        }, 
        {
            "amount" : 300,
            "purchased_price" : 900.0,
            "date_of_purchase" : "20170210 212426"
        }
    ]
},
```

I tried to use `$elemMatch` in mongo shell

```
db.Users.update({"user_info.user_name":"joe","portfolio":{$elemMatch:{"market_symbol":{$eq:"NASDAQ:GOOGL"},"details.purchased_price":{$eq:900}}}},{$set:{"portfolio.$.details.0.amount":300}})
```

It seems that the query always return the entire section of `"portfolio:market_symbol":"NASDAQ:GOOGL"`, because the `0` in `{$set:{"portfolio.$.details.0.amount":300}}` modifies the first array in `details`, whose `purchased_price` is `810.25`, rather than what I expect the `$elemMatch` to give me (the 3rd element from the array, whose `purchased_price` is `900`).

Is there a way that I can modify this nested nested array, rather than pulling the entire thing off, modify the data in my program, then write the entire thing back?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know,the positional operator only supports one level deep and only the first matching element.So that means updating all documents in array is not possible now.

There is a MongoDB JIRA ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

But you can update specific document manually.

```
db.test.find( 
{ "user_info.user_name":"joe", "portfolio.details.purchased_price" : 900.0 }).forEach(function(doc) { 
  doc.portfolio.forEach(function(item) { 
      item.details.forEach(function (amt){
            if (amt.purchased_price == 900.0)
                amt.amount=300
          });
      });
  db.test.update( { "user_info.user_name":"joe", "portfolio.details.purchased_price" : 900.0 }, { "$set": { "portfolio": doc.portfolio } });
});
```

It works for me.Hope this helps.